# Close menu after action was picked?

Tags: buttons, ios, menu, mobile-application, close

I have this menu on my iOS app where each button performs different action

1) Opens an iOS share extension (Share this app sort of thing)

2) Opens the app's inbox (Goes full screen - the lighter blue colour expands on the whole screen.

3) Opens the app's settings.

[image]

(These are not the icon's i'm gonna use, just an example)

My question is, Once a certain action was picked and i moved to the full screen display or the share extension, should i show the presented menu again when i exit one of the 3 modes? or should i close the menu entirly to look like this:

[image]

(This opens the previous image)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called **MARKING MENUS**. Once the user selects the desired option, close the options and set the menu item to default state.

[image]

You can read more at https://www.nngroup.com/articles/expandable-menus/

Once the user presses the menu handle, the menu gets expanded and the user can select an option by moving the finger in the direction of that option. As soon as the user lifts the finger, the highlighted option is selected and the menu disappears.